# How to use service worker in user script

Tags: service-worker, userscripts, tampermonkey

I want to **cache specific requests in someone's website**, then I find service worker a good choice. But I can't find any approach to **inject a service worker by tampermonkey**. So is there any hack to do this?

Answer (score -2):

What you *can* do is to overwrite windows.fetch to cache the calls. No need to use a service worker